# C if statement string condtions

Tags: c, string, if-statement

I'm trying to make my little program a little less tedious to test so I made an option to restart it. If I change RepeatC to an integer and state 1 is yes and 0 is no then this works no issue, but I can't seem to get my head around how to utilize strings in this capacity. As it stands it complies fine but crashes after it prints "Would you like to repeat the calculation? (Y/N)"

Ideally I'd like to have an array of strings, and in my experience with Python you could just inputedstring == "string 1", "string 2" .... or something like that, it's been a while, but you could create the array then and there.

Can't you do that in C? What would be the best way of going about it?

This is my code as it stands.

```
LOOP2:                                                                          //LOOP for error handling
    printf("Would you like to repeat the program? (Y/N)\n");        //Input request to restart
    scanf("%c", &RepeatC);                                                          //Scan for input
    if (strcmp(RepeatC, "yes")==0)                                                                  //Restart condition
    {
        goto LOOP1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(RepeatC, "no")==0)                                                              //End program condition
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else                                                                                                    //Error handling condition
    {
        printf("Your input was invalid. Please enter 1 for yes or 0 for no.\n");
        goto LOOP2;
    }
```

Comment: You should be able to figure out the *hangs* part by simply debugging.

Comment: How is `RepeatC` declared?

Comment: like this
 char RepeatC;

Comment: So `if(RepeatC == 'Y'  || RepeatC == 'y')` .... `if(RepeatC == 'N'  || RepeatC == 'n')`... also `scanf("%c", &RepeatC);` --> `scanf(" %c", &RepeatC);`

Comment: This at least lets me use a y/n answer, but it doesn't let me use longer strings which is what I would like to do. Still, helped me identify a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you Have declare `RepeatC` as a `char` then you don't have to use `strcmp()` function.**

you can directly use

```
if (RepeatC== 'Y'))  //Restart condition "Y" means 'Y''\0'
{
    goto LOOP1;
}
else if (RepeatC== 'N') //End program condition
{
    return 0;
}
else
```

And Before reading the `Y` and `N` form user you make sure that `RepeatC` will not contain `\0` in it

**If you have declare `RepeatC` as a string then you have to read the choice from user by using `%s` and then you can use the `strcmp()` function**

```
printf("Would you like to repeat the program? (Y/N)\n");     //Input request to restart
scanf("%s", &RepeatC);                                      //Scan for input
if (strcmp(RepeatC, "Y")==0)                                                                          //Restart condition
{
    goto LOOP1;
}
else if (strcmp(RepeatC, "N")==0)                                                              //End program condition
{
    return 0;
}
else                                                                                                    //Error handling condition
{
    printf("Your input was invalid. Please enter 1 for yes or 0 for no.\n");
    goto LOOP2;
}
```

Comment: How would I allow the user to also type in "Yes" and "No" as the answer?

Comment: By declaring `RepeatC ` as a array of `char` then use `%s` as a access specifier then user can type `Yes` and `No ` as a answer

Comment: Thanks buddy, helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

in C, you cannot use == to compare a string, while there is  no primitive data type as string in C. string in C is an array of char with '\0' appended at the end to indicate the end of string.
So, you should use strcmp to compare a array of character.

```
if (strcmp(RepeatC, "Y")==0)    //Restart condition "Y" means 'Y''\0'
{
    goto LOOP1;
}
else if (strcmp(RepeatC, "N")==0) //End program condition
{
    return 0;
}
else
```

Comment: I copy pasted that code you offered and it still hangs when it prints "Would you like to repeat the calculation? (Y/N)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ((strcmp(RepeatC, "Y")==0) || (strcmp(RepeatC, "y")==0)) {  //Restart condition "Y" means 'Y''\0'
    goto LOOP1;
}
else if ((strcmp(RepeatC, "N")==0) || (strcmp(RepeatC, "n")==0)) {  //End program condition
    return 0;
}
else
```

Comment: Still crashes at the same point